# Spring boot @Autowired can't initialise class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I have following class as:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ma.demospringboot")
public class DemoSpringBootApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringBootApp.class, args);
   }
}
```

I have following class as:-

```
@Service
public class TopicService {
    // if I comment out following autowired, then it is ok.
    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository; 
}
```

I have following interface as:-

```
public interface TopicRepository extends  CrudRepository<Topic, String> {
}
```

I have following class as:-

```
@Entity 
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic() {
    }
}
```

I got following error when try to execute:-

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

> Field topicRepository in com.ma.demospringboot.service.TopicService
>   required a bean of type
>   'com.ma.demospringboot.repository.TopicRepository' that could not be
>   found.

Action:

> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.ma.demospringboot.repository.TopicRepository' in your
>   configuration.

Comment: are your package names correct? Add the complete stacktrace and the package names to your classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring container is not finding your repository classes during the scan, **add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to explicitly specify the packages** of where your repository classes exist, as shown below:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan("com.ma.demospringboot")
  @EnableJpaRepositories("com.ma.demospringboot.repository")
  @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.ma.demospringboot.domain")
  public class DemoSpringBootApp {
      //your current code here
  }
```

**UPDATE1:**

> Not a managed type: class com.ma.demospringboot.domain.Topic

Now, your `Topic` entity class not found, so you need to `@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.ma.demospringboot.domain")` to scan the entity classes (as show above).

**UPDATE2:**

> I did exactly as you suggested, but NOT working

There is a problem with the way that you are packaging the classes, double check on that, also ensure that the latest classes have been compiled/built & used by the server.

Comment: Thanks. @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.ma.demospringboot.domain") fixed the error.

Comment: Or put your `DemoSpringBootApp` in `com.ma.demospringboot` instead of a suboackage and then you only need `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Spring` container is unable to find and identify your JPA repositories.

Add `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ma.demospringboot.repository")` on your `DemoSpringBootApp` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.ma.demospringboot")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ma.demospringboot.repository")
public class DemoSpringBootApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoSpringBootApp.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: After this. I get this:- 
Error creating bean with name 'topicController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'topicService'; nested exception is UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'topicService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'topicRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topicRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.ma.demospringboot.domain.Topic

Comment: @masiboo You can look at my answer

Comment: Yes. I did exactly as you suggested.

Comment: There are some problems the way you are packaging the classes, double check them

Comment: Try removing the constructor from Topic class.@masiboo

Answer (score 0):

add following code in your ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```